# Debug cordova app in emulator with android 4.1.2

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I'm creating cordova application which generally works except one case: when run on android 4.1.2 (and maybe older too) it doesn't communicate with the web-service when authentication is performed with use of certificate.

It works perfectly on devices and emulator with at least android 4.4 or 5.0.1.

I would like to debug the problem, but chrome inspect does not connect to the app (the 4.4 version of android and newer allows that) started on the emulator.

Unfortunately I have no access to device with android 4.1.2. I read about possibility of running chromium (see: https://paul.kinlan.me/installing-chrome-for-android-on-an-emulator/) but my app is running via WebView.

Is it possible to start my app with use of chromium? Or is there another way to debug my app with use of chrome inspector or anything else?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found a way to do this. With `adb` it is possible to read log generated on the device. So, essentially I will use javascript `console.log()` to print debug messages to the log and then `adb logcat` to show them (better useage: `adb logcat | grep D/CordovaLog` in order to filter out unnecessary records).

However, maybe there is a better way? Any help would be appreciated.